# Windows. Master volume control does not affect application's volume control

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

Searched the entire internet. I can not understand.

Clean Windows 10, fully updated.

The app volume is not adjusted when the master volume of the system is changed.

The problem with the fact that the real sound of applications does not change when changing the master volume.

- The software sound volume display ok.
- But the real sound volume
  isn't ok. (unfortunately I can not show the sound =))

When I decrease master volume, system sounds are quieter, but chrome is not If base settings master=100, chrome=100. I expect that when master=50, than chrome will 50 too.

But when master=50, chrome stay 100 in real, but by software it's 50 in one place and 100 in the second place.

And this problem persists for all apps (expect system's sounds) looks like changing the master only affects the system's sound

Only full mute works.

Tried:

- restarting **"Windows Audio"** service
- reinstalling drivers.
- most solutions from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-sound-or-audio-problems-in-windows-73025246-b61c-40fb-671a-2535c7cd56c8
  Nothing helps.

I don't think that the problem is with the headset, because it works fine on other PCs and another headsets have the same problem on the affected PC.
Problem with:

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎4/‎26/‎2022
OS build    19045.2728
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0
```

Other system don't have this problem with my headset (with Windows 10 Pro, Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Enterprise)

**UPD:**
"Volume mixer" shows real level of all apps, and "App volume and device preferences" shows percent of the master. *I checked displaying on the PC without this problem*
[image: see screenshot].

**SOLUTION:**
I uninstalled all recent updates Windows' updates and the problem gone. After that, I re-installed updates again and the problem didn't reoccur.
Looks like the root cause is wrong installed updates

Comment: The app volume is a percentage of the master volume

Comment: Oh yeah, and just to make sure: That audio device of yours does support software volume control, right? I have one audio interface that does not, it’s always at 100%.

Comment: What is this app?

Comment: All apps always at 100%, the sound stays the same
regardless of the master volume position

Comment: Others PCs\laptops with windows10 change the sound volume for all apps when I change the master volume.
I use my audio device (headset) at others PCs\laptops with windows10 and there is no any issues. I also tried to use other headsets, but nothing changed.
It's really like OS issue, but it's a fresh installation with fresh drivers. 
Perhaps is there some setting?

Comment: per [DanielB's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1775004/windows-master-volume-control-does-not-affect-applications-volume-control/1775013?noredirect=1#comment2767799_1775004) can you confirm the behavior persists when operating from speakers.  Also, please edit the question with pertinent details so that people trying to help don't need to navigate comments to get all the available info.

Comment: thanks everybody for assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all recent updates Windows' updates and the problem gone.

After that, I re-installed updates again and the problem didn't reoccur.

Looks like the root cause is wrong installed updates

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what worked for me was updating drivers and everything on the PC using Lenovo System Updates.

I work as desktop support at a large organization and one of our users reported this issue. I remoted in and experienced the same exact issues you did. I've never seen this before and couldn't find a solution after many troubleshooting attempts.

I actually created a Super User account for the first time ever just to comment on this.
I was on the verge of attempting your solution an uninstalling Windows Updates, but it ended up working after running Lenovo System Updates. Our enterprise primarily uses Lenovo machines, and we often use this software to run updates on all parts of the machine to address various issues.

I wasn't sure it would work and was already starting to think about which windows updates I could safely uninstall, but to my surprise when the user rebooted, he reported that the sound was working as intended now.

Comment: Thank you kind Sir. This helped me indeed. Never had a Lenovo System Updates on my laptop, but I downloaded it from lenovo's site, it found 1Gb of updates in total including recomended and optional. I just installed all of them so I don't now which one helped but sound control works now.

Answer (score 0):

Per [DavidPostill' comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1775004/windows-master-volume-control-does-not-affect-applications-volume-control#comment2767797_1775004) as well as the text in the image you provided in: "You can adjust volume for specific apps and system sounds as a percentage of the master volume."

Since it is a percentage, the number is expected to remain constant regardless how you adjusted the master volume level.

In your example image, master volume is set to 47 and Chrome's volume, relative to master, is set to 100%. 100% means Chrome's volume would **always match** the master volume.

Alternatively, if Chrome's volume were set to 50% of the master volume, you should expect different levels for Chrome relative to the master volume.  For example:

- `master=100` **:** `Chrome=50`
- `master=80` **:** `Chrome=40`
- `master=30` **:** `Chrome=15`

To test the relationship, set Chrone's relative volume to 20%, and master volume to 100 and compare the sound from Chrome in relation to a system sound.

#### *Older* "Volume Mixer"

Please note that you will be directed to the *newer* version of the "Volume Mixer", located in "Settings", whether opening the "Volume Mixer" by right-clicking the "Sound" icon in the "System Tray", or navigating to it via **`Settings > System > Sound > Volume mixer`**

If you prefer instead to access the *older* version of the "Volume Mixer",  the executable **`SndVol.exe`** is still included in Windows 10 & 11: **`C:\Windows\System32\SndVol.exe`**

<sub>**`SndVol.exe` Volume Mixer**</sub>
[image]

Comment: We have 2 types of sound volumes: software and real.
The software sound volume display ok. (Maybe)
But the real sound volume isn't ok. (unfortunately I can not show the sound =))
When I decrease master volume, system sounds are quieter, but chrome is not

If base settings  master=100, chrome=100
I expect that when master=50, than chrome will 50 too
But when master=50, chrome stay 100 in real, but by software it's 50 in one place and 100 in the second place

And this problem persists for all apps (expect system's sounds)
looks like changing the master only affects the system sound

Comment: I checked displaying on the another PC, "Volume mixer" shows real level of all apps, and 
"App volume and device preferences" shows percent of the master. The problem with the fact that the real sound of applications does not change when changing the master

Comment: the question was updated

Comment: You still have not responded with respect to  [DanielB's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1775004/windows-master-volume-control-does-not-affect-applications-volume-control/1775013?noredirect=1#comment2767799_1775004) also include the make and model of the headset

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with the headset, because it works fine on other PCs and another headsets have the same problem on the affected PC

Comment: Thank you for assist. I found a solution and updated the question